# Stream Webcam to Windows pc

Tags: wifi, windows, webcam, streaming

Does anyone know how I can stream the webcam from my raspberrypi to my windows pc via wifi?

Ive tried gstreamer but this just doesnt work for me and ive read the performance is really bad.

there has to be another way

thanks in advance

Comment: Your options will depend on the power of your RPi. Which model is it? What kind of webcam are you using? Are you ok using scripts (shell, Python)?

Comment: The raspberry need a licence key for hardware decoding of additional codecs (not on the Pi4). Also, you need to adapt the framerate to the hardware and network performances.  `1 - ` Mount Wi-Fi Access Point on your raspberry  `2 - ` connect your Windows client to this WAP  `3 -` Run python script webserver (use picamera example webserver stream) on your Raspberry. `4 -` Open web-browser on windows and navigate to the good IP or name (your RPi name or IP addr), 5- Show your stream !